# UITableView background filled only half?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, background

I filled my `tableView` with a background view (gradient) unfortunately, only half of the background is filled.

Any ideas how to fill the second half?

Big thanks in advance!

Code:

```
UIView* myView = [[GradientBackground alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height)];

myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

myTableView.backgroundView = myView;
```

and **Gradientbackground.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       
CGGradientRef glossGradient;
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = {  25.0 / 255.0, 89.0 / 255.0, 140.0 / 255.0, 0.65,  // Start color
25.0 / 255.0, 89.0 / 255.0, 140.0 / 255.0, 1.0 }; // End color


//( 25.0 / 255.0 ) green:( 89.0 / 255.0 ) blue:( 140.0 / 255.0 )

rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);

CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace); 
} 

25.0 / 255.0, 89.0 / 255.0, 140.0 / 255.0, 1.0 }; // End color


//( 25.0 / 255.0 ) green:( 89.0 / 255.0 ) blue:( 140.0 / 255.0 )

rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);

CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. My code for the gradient was wrong. I used the mid of the view, but the gradient was supposed to end at the bottom.

```
rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(currentBounds));
CGPoint bottomCent = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMinY(currentBounds));
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, bottomCent, 0);

CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the autoresizemask on myView? Try setting it to variable height and width.

Also you're setting the frame of myView to self.bounds instead of myTableView.bounds.

Comment: Tried this `UIView* myView = [[GradientBackground alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myTableView.bounds.origin.x, myTableView.bounds.origin.y, myTableView.bounds.size.width,  myTableView.bounds.size.height)];
    
    myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` but I had no luck.